# Probability of shooting a 10 in archery?

Tags: probability, statistics

I was interested in calculating the probability of shooting a 10 in archery with the scores that one has already shot. (Yes, that may include misses)

My approach to do this was to simply assume a normailzed curve created by my scores. I would find out the mean and the variance of my scores, and then, wanting a score of 10, Id go on to see what the Z-value for a standard normal curve would be:

\begin{equation}
Z = \frac{x-x_0}{\sigma}
\end{equation}

The value though that I get seems a bit too low for me. (I used on the GDC the normalcdf function). Even if I would shoot pure tens except maybe the last shot, which I finish with a 9, I would still end up only with a 40% chance of getting a 10....

Any ideas to what I might be doing wrong? Thanks for all suggestions!

Comment: What does "with the scores that one has already shot" mean?

Comment: It means, based on the shots and scores that I have collected previously, what would my probability be, that by the next shot, I shoot a 10? So you are relying on the shots you shot before.